# systemd service "installer" which reinstalls other subsequent services which do not start up in this case

Tags: systemd

What could be the reason, why could it not work and how to solve the problem?

I have an "installer" and several other "firmware" services which are registered to systemd and normally start on Linux booting. Usually the "installer" service has nothing to do in its script.

installer service:

```
[Unit]
Description=INSTALLER
Before=network-pre.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/product/sbin/do-installer.sh
StandardOutput=journal+console
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

typical firmware service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Firmware
Wants=network.target multi-user.target systemd-hostnamed.service connman.service installer.service
After=network.target multi-user.target systemd-hostnamed.service connman.service installer.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/product/sbin/firmware.sh
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The firmware update mechanism works in the way that during booting the "installer" service sometimes detects there's something to do, and then it immediately calls its firmware update script which is executed and finishes before the network comes up. Firmware update means to deinstall and to install the firmware service.

I have the problem that after such reinstallation the firmware service does not start. I always have to reboot again to get the newly installed firmware start up. I don't understand the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've found a solution for myself: My script do-installer.sh not only has to call

```
opkg install ... all the stuff ...
systemctl start firmware1.service &
systemctl start firmware2.service &
...
systemctl start firmwareN.service &
```

but additionally also these two commands which solved my problem:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reset-failed
```